# Decimal to BASE-26 representation

Tags: c, number-systems

I wrote code to convert a decimal number to a corresponding alphabetical representation.

Examples:

```
1: A
2: B
.
.
.
26: Z
27: AA
.
.
.
703: AAA
```

Here is my approach:

```
void print(int n)
{
    if( n > 0 )
    {
        n--;
        print( n / 26 );
        printf( "%c", ( n % 26 ) + 'A' );
    }
}
```

The above code is [working correctly](http://ideone.com/tMBAE). Can I optimize it in terms of readability?
What is the best way to do it?

Now, I want to modify the above code to work like this:

```
0: A
1: B
.
.
.
25: Z
26: AA
.
.
.
702: AAA
```

The obvious approach is to add 1 to the input decimal number and pass it to the function in the original code.
How can I modify the first program to work it for the second case without adding 1?

Comment: You have a pretty odd idea how how base-26 would work; you seem to be missing a zero...

Comment: @R.. Please look at the code carefully. Its not converting to Base 26. Observe n--

Comment: I meant the example, not the code. If the base is 26, there should not be a symbol (Z) with value 26...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some observations, i have tried the below code & its working for the `Case: 2`.

```
void print(int n)
{
    if(n < 26)
        printf("%c", n + 'A');
    else
    {
        print(n / 26 - 1);

        print(n % 26);
    }
}
```

See output [here](http://ideone.com/Qvlec).